# WinRM or PowerShell Server?

Tags: ssh, powershell, remote

I would like to be able to remote into my Windows machines with a command line only interface, to PowerShell. It must be secure.

It seems like there are two options for doing this. One is the (barely) out-of-the-box WinRM way, and the other is by installing third-party [PowerShell Server](http://www.powershellserver.com/).

So far here's what I've gathered:

PowerShell Server cons

- requires installation of software
- does not allow powershell to use its inbuilt `-computername` parameter on different cmdlets

WinRM cons (as far as i can tell)

- has difficulty working across domains
- does not generate a certificate automatically
- requires generation of a new certificate for each domain/hostname/ip for a machine
- can't use other terminal clients, or login from a linux machine
- not documented very well

Are these considerations accurate? Is there anything else I should be taking into consideration?

Comment: http://www.powershellserver.com/powershell-server-compared-to-powershell-v2-remoting-via-winrm/ suggests there is an add-on library that can enable execution of remote PS objects with PowerShell Server.....

Comment: Yeah I've read that. Frankly requiring extra software to be installed for PowerShell Server is already almost a deal-breaker for me, needing an add-on on top of that is kind of out of the question. What I was really hoping for was someone to tell me WinRM isn't as difficult as it seems.